# flutter pdf long table

Tags: dart, pdf, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter . I am try to design a pdf file that have a long table. but table don't split automatically . if the table longer than an a4 size the pdf file will not generate. is there a simple solution for that I am missing?

if the counter is longer than 25 the pdf will not generate.
yes I know for one table it easy to use if/else function and generate two tables but in my main project I have multiple tables that have different columns numbers. so I need a solution that make the tables split automatically.

---

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;
Future<void> testPdf() async {
  final Document pdf = Document();
  var myFont = Font.ttf(await rootBundle.load("assets/fonts/HacenTunisia.ttf"));
  List<TableRow> buildTable(
      { Context context, int count = 10, bool repeatHeader = false}) {
    final rows = <TableRow>[];
    {
      final tableRow = <Widget>[];
      for (final cell in <String>['Hue', 'Color', 'RGBA']) {
        tableRow.add(Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Text(cell, style: Theme.of(context).tableHeader)));
      }
      rows.add(TableRow(children: tableRow, repeat: repeatHeader));
    }
    for (var y = 0; y < count; y++) {
      final h = math.sin(y / count) * 365;
      final PdfColor color = PdfColorHsv(h, 1.0, 1.0);
      final tableRow = <Widget>[
        Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Text('${h.toInt()}°', style: Theme.of(context).tableCell)),
        Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: color,

            ),
            height: Theme.of(context).tableCell.fontSize),
        Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Text(color.toHex(), style: Theme.of(context).tableCell)),
      ];
      rows.add(TableRow(children: tableRow));
    }
    return rows;
  }
  pdf.addPage(MultiPage(
      theme: ThemeData.withFont(
        base: myFont,
      ),
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (Context context) {
        return [
          Column(children: [

            Container(
              // margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(22, 5, 22, 5),
              child: Directionality(
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                child: Table(
                  children: buildTable(context: context, count: 30),
                  border: TableBorder.all(),
                  tableWidth: TableWidth.max,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
          ])
        ];
      }));
  final String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  //final String VoucherNo =request['VoucherNo'];
  final String path = '$dir/1.pdf';
  final File file = File(path);
  await file.writeAsBytes(pdf.save());
  await Printing.sharePdf(bytes: pdf.save(), filename: 'report.pdf');
}
```

Comment: You can use pw.ListView.builder and take the index and sort it , to divide all tables you should write all the codes again for every different table.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any package ?
You can try [SPDF package](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer)

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late for the answer, stil in case it would help anyone
you can try using Table.textArray which will split the table , when the current page is full.

Comment: no, thank you bother this really helpful for me to know. Yes now I don't work with flutter. but I need to know does these was working before or is't new thing they add it? because I remember that I search a lot to solve this problem .

Comment: i think it was already there in that package